# What is the difference between the "c99" and "gcc" commands with appropriate flags?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

Up until today I always read on the Internet how gcc is the best compiler for C (at least for the student level of programing, followed closely by Clang).
However in "[21st Century C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449327141)" Mr Ben Klemens suggests that c99 is better(?)  than running `gcc -std=c99` (actual line is [page 11]: *everybody else switched to C99 being the default a long
time ago*...)

I wasn't able to find anything on the subject of c99 compiler, so my question is:

Is there any difference between those commands and if there are, which one is better?

EDIT: The standard C99 is clearly metioned in the paragraph, however from the beginning the suggested method of compiling is the command:

```
 gcc erf.c -o erf -lm -g -Wall -O3 -std=gnu11
```

However on page 11 the author states:

*The POSIX standard specifies that c99 be present on your system, so the
compiler-agnostic version of the above line would be:*

```
c99 erf.c -o erf -lm -g -Wall -O3
```

This seems to suggest there is a difference in those 2 commands. I wasn't able to find any additional info nor was it clear to me from the text, what the second line is exactly (no man page for c99 on my Cygwin either).

Comment: C99 is the standard. Current (and only valid) standard is C11. It is not a compiler. gcc mostly complies to the standard, although it does not provide the C standard library (except for some header-only parts), thus you need that from another source, e.g. GNU libc.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: @Olaf I'm aware of the C99 standard, but the author uses the command 'gcc --std=gnu99 erf.c -lm` etc. to show readers, how to compile.Later on the author switches to the command 'c99 erf.c -lm' etc. Maybe those two command both mean the same, but that just wasn't clear to me from the text itself.

Comment: You did not state that in your question. Please read [ask]. Briefly, a question has to be self-contained and must not rely on external links. If you expect someone to know the contents of the linked object, you better ask at that site.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry for being too vague... I edited the question to (hopefully) explain it a little better.

Comment: Probably, `c99` is just an alias to `gcc -std=gnu99`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `c99 --version` on a typical Linux box. You will get the version and name of the compiler which is `gcc`.

`c99` is just a shortcut to the c99 compliant compiler on your machine. That way you don't have to care about the actual compiler used. POSIX also requires some common command line options the compiler has to understand. If that is gcc, it shall enable c99 compliant features. This should be identical to `gcc -std=c99`.

gcc provides additional features which are enabled by default [1] when called by its native name and by the `-std=gccXX` option in addition to the CXX standard. For older versions, some of these extensions became part of the next C standard either directly or with slightly different syntax. A typical and appreciated extension for C90 is support for C++-style line-comments:

```
// this is not allowed in pure C90
```

For c99/gnu99 things are less obvious, but might still add some usefull features.

On other POSIX systems, e.g. Unix, you may find a different compiler. It shall still be available by the name `c99`.

Note that the current and only valid C standard is C11 since 2011. So if you want to use the new features (e.g. atomics, thread-support), you have to deviate from the pure POSIX-path. Yet it is likely POSIX might be updated some day.

---

[1] The default version of the C standard depends on the version of gcc. pre5 used C90, while gcc 5.x uses C11.

Answer (score 5):

C99 is the 1999 edition of the ISO C standard.  It replaced the 1990 standard, and has been (officially, at least) replaced by the 2011 standard.

What you're asking about, though, is the `c99` command (I've updated your question's title to clarify that).

POSIX specifies a `c99` command. The requirements are documented [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html). It is "an interface to the standard C compilation system".

On typical Linux systems, the `c99` command `/usr/bin/c99` is a small shell script that invokes the `gcc` commmand. It invokes `gcc` with the `-std=c99` option. It also checks whether the user has already specified an equivalent option, so it doesn't use the same option twice. If an incompatible option has been given, such as `c99 -std=c90`, it terminates with an error message.

Given such an implementation, the command

```
c99 [args]
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
gcc -std=c99 [args]
```

As I mentioned above, the C99 standard has been officially superseded by the C11 standard.  gcc version 5 (the current latest release is 5.3.1) has reasonably good support but not 100% complete support for C11. POSIX has not (yet) specified a `c11` command.

There's nothing wrong with using the C99 standard if you don't need C11-specific features -- or even the C90 standard if you don't need C99-specific features.

Comment: IIRC C99 has some subtle different semantics compared to C90.

Answer (score 3):

In my PDF copy of the book, the discussion about using `c99` instead of `gcc -std=c99` seems to be on page 10, not 11.

And what is being discussed is not that `c99` is "better" than `gcc`, but that you might be able to more easily use C99-standard compiler features with the `c99` command, since you don't then need to know the specific option to enable C99 features or whether the default for the compiler is C99 or C89.

On my system, the command `c99` is just an alias or link for `gcc` that has the `-std=c99` set by default (and complains if a non-C99 standard is specified with the `-std=` option).  I imagine that or something similar is true on most systems with a `c99` compiler command.

In fact, on my system `c99` is a link to a shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Call the appropriate C compiler with options to accept ANSI/ISO C
# The following options are the same (as of gcc-3.3):
#   -std=c99
#   -std=c9x
#   -std=iso9899:1999
#   -std=iso9899:199x

extra_flag=-std=c99

for i; do
    case "$i" in
    -std=c9[9x]|-std=iso9899:199[9x])
        extra_flag=
        ;;
    -std=*|-ansi)
        echo >&2 "`basename $0` called with non ISO C99 option $i"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

exec gcc $extra_flag ${1+"$@"}
```